# SQL Server : partial group by on single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum, partial

Already asked a similar question earlier in the day and the solution led me to another question (after example):

- I have these columns two of which are quantities.
- Of which one (LotQty) is a sum, grouped by Productid and Lot.
- The other (SumQuantity) must be sum of the former grouped only by Productid.

The result should look like this:

```
SumQuantity    Productid  LotQty        Lot
----------------------------------------------------
 512           40652      256.000000    2020-12-20
 512           40652      256.000000    2020-12-21
1024           40661      512.000000    2019-12-19
1024           40661      512.000000    2019-12-20
 512           40710      256.000000    2021-03-03
 512           40710      256.000000    2021-04-04
```

I.e. SumQuantity = sum(LotQty) group by productid, while sum(LotQty) is grouped by productid AND lot.

```
select 
    sum(sum(s.cuquantity)) over () SumQuantity,
    s.productid, sum(s.cuquantity) LotQty, la.Value Lot 
from 
    log l 
left join 
    logstock s on s.logid = l.id
left join 
    Logstockattributes la on la.LogStockID = s.id and la.AttributeID = 10
where  
    l.receiptid = 5950195
group by 
    productid, la.value
```

The result is:

```
SumQuantity  Productid    LotQty        Lot
---------------------------------------------------
2048         40652        256.000000    2020-12-20
2048         40652        256.000000    2020-12-21
2048         40661        512.000000    2019-12-19
2048         40661        512.000000    2019-12-20
2048         40710        256.000000    2021-03-03
2048         40710        256.000000    2021-04-04
```

Sample table

```
  Logid        Productid      Cuquantity    Lot
  -----------------------------------------------------
  1            40652          256.000000    2020-12-20
  2            40652          255.000000    2020-12-21
  3            40652            1.000000    2020-12-21
  4            40661          512.000000    2019-12-19
  5            40661          512.000000    2019-12-20
  6            40710          256.000000    2021-03-03
  7            40710          255.000000    2021-04-04
  8            40710            1.000000    2021-04-04
```

How should I change my select to get the result I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need `partition by`:

```
select sum(sum(s.cuquantity)) over (partition by productid) as SumQuantity,
       s.productid, sum(s.cuquantity) as LotQty, la.Value as Lot 
from log l left join
     logstock s
     on s.logid = l.id left join
     Logstockattributes la
     on la.LogStockID = s.id and la.AttributeID = 10
where l.receiptid = 5950195
group by productid,la.value
```

Comment: i hadn't used "over()" till now and i hadn't used "partion by" till now...it looks like it works in the tests, i hope i got it right and it would work in the real world :) 10x a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the partition by and remove the extra `SUM`. Essentially, you want window functions instead of the full aggregate method so that you can return the row level details.

```
select distinct
    SumQuantity = sum(Cuquantity) over (partition by Productid),
    LotQty = sum(Cuquantity) over (partition by Productid, Lot),
    Productid,
    Lot
from log l 
left join logstock s on s.logid=l.id
left join Logstockattributes la on la.LogStockID=s.id and la.AttributeID=10
where l.receiptid=5950195
la.value
```